# Only show Unique ID greater than x seconds in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I am trying to figure out how to only output unique IDs that are above 30 seconds in this array. to make it simple it just needs to grab the first value over 30 seconds for a unique ID.

```
$array = array(
0 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'seconds' => '36'
),
1 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'seconds' => '60'
),
2 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'seconds' => '36'
),
3 => array(
    'id' => '2',
    'seconds' => '22'
),
4 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'seconds' => '36'
),
5 => array(
    'id' => '2',
    'seconds' => '36'
),
6 => array(
    'id' => '3',
    'seconds' => '44'
),
7 => array(
    'id' => '3',
    'seconds' => '2'
),
8 => array(
    'id' => '4',
    'seconds' => '58'
),
9 => array(
    'id' => '6',
    'seconds' => '9'
),
10 => array(
    'id' => '6',
    'seconds' => '8'
));
```

Ideal result would look like this

```
$arrayResult = array(
0 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'seconds' => '36'
),
1 => array(
    'id' => '2',
    'seconds' => '36'
),
2 => array(
    'id' => '3',
    'seconds' => '44'
),
3 => array(
    'id' => '4',
    'seconds' => '58'
));
```

Currently I can only get unique values for the ID's without having the seconds correlated with the 'id' field.

Comment: Is this data coming from a DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce` to iterate over the `$array` and extract only values that you want.

```
$array = array_reduce($array, function ($unique, $entry) {
    extract($entry);

    if (! isset($unique[$id]) && $seconds > 30) {
        $unique[$id] = $entry;
    }

    return $unique;
}, []);

$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly this seems more efficient that what I was doing with array_unique ();

Answer (score 1):

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($array as $val)
{
    if($val['seconds'] > 30 && (!array_key_exists($val['id'], $final_array))){
        $final_array[$val['id']] = $val;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

if you want to reset array keys then you can use

```
$final_array = array_values($final_array);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_array);
echo "</pre>";
```